# How do I access node body from template.php?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

Here is my code so far:

```
if (!empty($page['content']['system_main']['nodes']) && is_array($page['content']['system_main']['nodes'])) {
    foreach ($page['content']['system_main']['nodes'] as $nid => &$content) {

        // Blog
        if ($content['#node']->type == 'blog') {
            $description = ???;
        }

    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to access the node's unformatted body field, I can't believe it's so difficult to achieve such a simple task..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out the content type within template.php?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11486/how-do-i-find-out-the-content-type-within-template-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11486/how-do-i-find-out-the-content-type-within-template-php) has the answer - `$page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['body'][0]['#markup']`

Answer (score 1):

It all depends where exactly you want to access it from.

For example in [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6) you have full node object in `$variables['node']`, including `body` field (`$variables['node']->body`).

Comment: Ahah sorry, I'm using THEME_page_alter($page) {}

Comment: Then well, yes, that's what you get. Perhaps it's just not the best place to do such operations. Perhaps you should consider using <code>template_preprocess_node()</code>, or even <code>hook_node_view()</code> (I guess we're talking D7 here).

Comment: Well I need it to affect the meta description on all of my site's pages, and would rather have it all in one hook function.

Comment: Ah, you should have said so from the start. As in this case probably your solution wouldn't cut it either, as not always you're going to deal with single nodes. I'd suggest you have a peak how for example Meta tags (http://drupal.org/project/metatag) or Meta tags quick (http://drupal.org/project/metatags_quick) are doing it...

Comment: Well thanks for your suggestion, I just tried both of those modules and neither of them seem to work. I followed the instructions well, and am an experienced web dev... and yet it just won't work. Drupal has been REALLY testing my patience of late.

Comment: I configured all the settings, cleared caches, ran cron... what on earth am I doing wrong? It can't just be me being stupid..