# How to get body field within THEME_page_alter

Tags: entities, nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access node body from template.php?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11558/how-do-i-access-node-body-from-template-php)

I've actually asked this previously, but I received an unsatisfactory answer, and thus my question was forgotten, as it was marked 'answered'.

My aim is to have a meta description on my front page, and a meta description for each of my blog entries, I'm using THEME_page_alter to achieve this. Both the metatag and metatags_quick modules don't seem to work properly despite several hours of changing settings.

Here is the code located in my template.php:

```
function vertaxe_page_alter($page) {
    $description = 'My default desc';
    if (!empty($page['content']['system_main']['nodes']) && is_array($page['content']['system_main']['nodes'])) {
        foreach ($page['content']['system_main']['nodes'] as $nid => &$content) {
            if ($content['#node']->type == 'blog') {
                $description = '';
            }

        }
    }

    $meta_description = array(
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'name' => 'description',
            'content' =>  $description
        )
    );

    drupal_add_html_head( $meta_description, 'meta_description' );

}
```

How do I get the node's body field for use in my description?

Comment: I realise I'm repeating myself, but I wasn't getting an answer (or at least one that worked, or that I could understand)

Comment: You asked the same question three times. If you want to get more attention for your questions because the existing answers don't satisfy you, then you need to wait until you cannot offer a bounty for your questions.

Comment: I do apologise, I'm rather frustrated :) But do you think you can help me now? The Devel module indicates that the body field should be in `$page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['body']['#object']['body']['und'][‌​0]['value']`

Answer (score 2):

According the [hook_page_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) documentation you should be able find the body like that.

```
$description = $page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['body'];
```

But if you still have the problem you can display all data from your page with the help of [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module or simply with a `print_r($page);` and look where is the content that you're looking for.

Comment: Someone suggested that before, I'm getting `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\vertaxe\includes\common.inc on line 2264`, i'll try the Devel module.

Comment: So the Devel module indicated that the content should be in `$page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['body']['#object']['body']['und'][0]['value']` but still no luck, it produces the stdClass error.